# Why If statement returns undefined for hashTable?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, hashtable

Can someone explains this JavaScript quirk?

An example:

```
function func(hashTable) {
  if (hashTable['foo'])
    return true;
}

var hash = {};
hash['foo'] = 0;
func(hash);
```

I get `undefined` instead of `true`.

Comment: `(hashTable['foo'])` evaluates to false when its value is 0 so `return true` is skipped. Then undefined is returned.

Comment: @KaisinLi , for what condition you want the if block to execute?

Comment: @RohitAgrawal originally I was trying to check if hashTable has key 'foo'. But as you suggested, hasOwnProperty is a better way to go.

Answer (score 5):

That's because you `returned` the function for a single **covered** situation(when `hastTable['foo']` is true).

`hashTable['foo']` is `0` and `if(0)` is interpreted as `false` and you do not have **returned** value for this case.

In **JavaScript**, and not only JavaScript, we have so called `falsy` **values**. These are respectively: `0`, `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `""`, `NaN`.

Comment: Ah I see, I was missing the "if(0) is interpreted as false part". Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`hashTable['foo']` has value `0` which evaluates to boolean `false`. Hence `if` block is never executed.

If you want to the if block to execute when `hashTable` has a property `foo`(or any other property) irrespective of its value you can do it in this way:

```
function func (hashTable) {
  return hashTable.hasOwnProperty("foo");
}

var hash = {}
hash['foo'] = 0;
console.log(func (hash));
```

Comment: This answer is missing some important things. You could do `return hashTable.hasOwnProperty("foo");`, theres no need for an if statement at all

Comment: Thank you @Jonasw. Just forgot that. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe shorter & better:

```
const func = table => "foo" in table;
```

And hashtables should be constructed like this:

```
const hash = Object.create(null);
```

---

And since ES 6 theres a better construct for such things:

```
const hash = new Map();
//to check
hash.has("foo")
```

Comment: The problem with Map is if 'foo' has value 0, hash['foo'] would return undefined

Comment: @kaisin because its `hash.get("foo")`

Answer (score 0):

To check whether an object contains a particular property, use `in` or `.hasOwnProperty()`.

`in` produces a `true` value if the property is present on the object or anywhere on its prototype chain.

`.hasOwnProperty()` returns `true` if the property is present on the object itself (prototype is not checked).

```js
function Student(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
 
Student.prototype.occupation = 'student';

var john = new Student('John');

// in
console.log('name' in john);        // true
console.log('occupation' in john);  // true
console.log('age' in john);         // false

// .hasOwnProperty()
console.log(john.hasOwnProperty('name'));       // true
console.log(john.hasOwnProperty('occupation')); // false
console.log(john.hasOwnProperty('age'));        // false
```

Answer (score -1):

Becz return happen only when hashTable['foo'] is true;

hashTable['foo'] is false since you have assigned 0;

so...
function func (hashTable) {
  if (hashTable['foo']){
    return true
  }else{
    return false
  }
}